# Keyboard configuation

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, kde, language-support

I'm running Kubuntu 20.04 with KDE Plasma 5.18.5 in English.

It seems impossible to configure an USA International keyboard layout to work with Brazilian Portuguese language and its special characters (like 'á', 'à', 'ç', 'ã' and many others).

Could anyone please help me on this? I have wasted too much time on this.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Many Brazilian users use the _English (US, intl., with dead keys)_ layout. If that's not sufficient for your needs, please be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Go to:
System Settings -> Keyboard -> Layout -> Add

Then select:

- Language: `Portuguese`
- Layout: `Portuguese (Brazilian)`